# I want to know how my packet reach to google server, when I type google.com in browser?

Tags: networking, routing-table

I have started learning about networking.
I want to know **how routing table works**. lets say if I type google.com in my browser, It will somehow reach to my ISP. But, from my ISP how it will reach to googles server?

Comment: What did your research tell you? [Networking 101: Understanding BGP Routing](http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netsp/article.php/3615896/Networking-101-Understanding-BGP-Routing.htm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a packet reach its destination?](http://superuser.com/questions/710132/how-does-a-packet-reach-its-destination)

Answer (score 1):

```
traceroute google.com
```

"       traceroute - print the route packets trace to network host"